# Access rendering items multiple times on top of each other

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

We have an Access 2010-application, which periodically renders items on top of each other.
It's periodically - one customer can experience it on one form, but others don't. Then next time the customer opens the form, everything's fine.

[image: Image of Access runtime rendering error]

I cannot find any information about this, so do any of you guys know what could solve the issue?

Comment: It seems to be a problem on only check boxes and radio buttons.

Comment: What Operating System(s) are you seeing this on?

Comment: Is there any VBA changing position and/or visibility of controls in your form?

Comment: @Rikalous, its for both Windows 7 and Windows 10

Comment: is this using the Access runtime or a 'full-fat' instance of Access? (Unhandled Exception's question is pertinent too)

Comment: @Rikalous, it's Access runtime (sorry for the late reply).